# AngularJs ui-router state.templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have an MVC 5 app with areas and I am trying to use the ui-router for AngularJs within one of my areas but I noticed that the templateUrl is wrong. It is trying to use a relative path but since I am using MVC routes and an Area the path to the template is incorrect.

The url to my area controller action is localhost:3789/Admin/UserManager .
The actual path is /Areas/Admin/Scripts/app/usermanager/partials/userlist.html .

```
angular.module("bsAdmin.userManager", ["ngResource", "ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "bsPromiseTracker", "bsBusy", "angular-growl", "ngAnimate"])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

// default state
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/userlist");

$stateProvider
    .state('userlist', {
        url: "/userlist",
        templateUrl: "partials/userlist.html"
    });

});
```

Angular ui-router tries to load the partial template using localhost:3789/Admin/partials/userlist.html

What are some techniques I can use so that the script will use the correct url to load the partial?

Comment: Not sure but if this url `localhost:3789/Admin/UserManager` renders the view when pasted in browser, you can use `templateurl:admin/usermanager`. The idea is the url should result in html being send back.

Answer (score 0):

If your Angular javascript is in your .cshtml file, you can use the ASP.NET MVC URL helper to build the URL.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('userlist', {
        url: "/userlist",
        templateUrl: "@Url.Content("~partials/userlist.html")"
    });

});
```

Comment: It's not, I have it in .js files... what I ended up doing for now, unless i find a better way was just to use the full path "/Areas/Admin/Scripts/app/usermanager/partials/userlist.html".